# Python-sklearn I'm triying to calculate the Full Width at Half Maximum of a function using

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm triying to calculate the Full Width at Half Maximum of a discret data, for that, i'm  using PolynomialFeatures to calculate a function that fits to the data but my problem comes when im looking for the X value of the Half Maximum of the function I'm using np.max(Y)/2 to calculate the exact point but i don't know how to get the X value. Please Help!.

```
Y = [[ 0.05803067],[ 0.07689777],[ 0.09969783],[ 0.12724925],[ 0.16009712],[ 0.19848337],[ 0.2412333 ],[ 0.28760687],[ 0.3363426 ],[ 0.38639457],[ 0.43342544],[ 0.4756857 ],[ 0.51185399],[ 0.54060251],[ 0.55957097],[ 0.56814678],[ 0.56643735],[ 0.55509265],[ 0.53498032],[ 0.50782052],[ 0.47466232],[ 0.43803997],[ 0.39971364],[ 0.36051318],[ 0.32043068],[ 0.28133987],[ 0.2448417 ],[ 0.21164328],[ 0.18123273],[ 0.15370787],[ 0.1290583 ]]
X = [[ 26.93751667],[ 26.4203759 ],[ 25.91246191],[ 25.41297357],[ 24.92152611],[ 24.43820595],[ 23.9623504 ],[ 23.49360564],[ 23.0316473 ],[ 22.5764841 ],[ 22.12762301],[ 21.6850423 ],[ 21.24818264],[ 20.81725687],[ 20.39174577],[ 19.9716062 ],[ 19.55667297],[ 19.14678168],[ 18.74177049],[ 18.34155481],[ 17.94596771],[ 17.55484964],[ 17.16810944],[ 16.78570687],[ 16.40742118],[ 16.03326047],[ 15.66306224],[ 15.29672179],[ 14.93417937],[ 14.57536814],[ 14.22021619]]
degree = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
for deg in degree:
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(deg),
                      linear_model.LinearRegression())
    model.fit(X, Y)
    print(model.score(X, Y))[enter image description here][1]
    plt.plot(X, model.predict(X), "-b", c='r')
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', c = 'b')
    print(model.predict(np.max(Y)/2))
plt.show()
```

The values i'm looking for should be right in the edges of the green line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling model.predict(np.max(Y)/2) you're calculating the y value at x=np.max(Y)/2. I don't know if there is an inverse function for scikit-learn, however you can calculate the x value at np.max(Y)/2 using the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn import linear_model


Y = [[ 0.05803067],[ 0.07689777],[ 0.09969783],[ 0.12724925],[ 0.16009712],[ 0.19848337],[ 0.2412333 ],[ 0.28760687],[ 0.3363426 ],[ 0.38639457],[ 0.43342544],[ 0.4756857 ],[ 0.51185399],[ 0.54060251],[ 0.55957097],[ 0.56814678],[ 0.56643735],[ 0.55509265],[ 0.53498032],[ 0.50782052],[ 0.47466232],[ 0.43803997],[ 0.39971364],[ 0.36051318],[ 0.32043068],[ 0.28133987],[ 0.2448417 ],[ 0.21164328],[ 0.18123273],[ 0.15370787],[ 0.1290583 ]]
X = [[ 26.93751667],[ 26.4203759 ],[ 25.91246191],[ 25.41297357],[ 24.92152611],[ 24.43820595],[ 23.9623504 ],[ 23.49360564],[ 23.0316473 ],[ 22.5764841 ],[ 22.12762301],[ 21.6850423 ],[ 21.24818264],[ 20.81725687],[ 20.39174577],[ 19.9716062 ],[ 19.55667297],[ 19.14678168],[ 18.74177049],[ 18.34155481],[ 17.94596771],[ 17.55484964],[ 17.16810944],[ 16.78570687],[ 16.40742118],[ 16.03326047],[ 15.66306224],[ 15.29672179],[ 14.93417937],[ 14.57536814],[ 14.22021619]]
degree = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

for deg in degree:
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(deg),
                  linear_model.LinearRegression())
    model.fit(X, Y)
    plt.plot(X, model.predict(X), "-b", c='r')
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', c = 'b')
    cont=[]
    for val in X:
      if model.predict([val])-np.max(Y)/2<0.0001:

         cont.append(val[0])

    hfwidth=np.abs(cont[-1]-cont[0])
    print('Left x value ' + str(cont[0])+' '+'Right x value ' + str(cont[-1])+'  '+'Full width ' +str(hfwidth))

plt.show()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i've test it but it gives me the Full width of the first and the last element of the model.predict, not the elements in X that corresponds to np.max(Y)/2, thanks for your help, i really appreciate it, is the first time i see the np.abs function it would help me

Comment: All the X elements that correspond to np.max(Y)/2 can be found in cont, so you can use them as you need them.